# I need to compare two lists and check if a string from list1 is in list2

Tags: python, list

So I will have two lists like this:

```
list1 = ['p', '-x', 'q123', '-q3']
list2 = ['p56', '-p', '-q123', 'xr']
```

So lets say if

***CASE 1***: an item from `list1 == 'p'` I need to check if '-p' is in list2 or,

***CASE 2***: an item from `list1== '-p'` I need to check if 'p' is on list2.

And then delete the element from list1 if any of these cases are triggered, so that I'm only left with elements that only appear in its negative form or only appear in its positive form. Right now I am able to do the CASE 1, but I'm not sure how to do CASE 2.

```
    
list1 = ['p', '-x', 'q123', '-q3']
list2 = ['p56', '-p', '-q123', 'xr']
new_list1 = list1.copy()
for y in list1:
    for x in list2:
        if x == '-'+y:
            new_list1.remove(y)
```

For these two lists I would be left with only when I handle both cases

```
new_list1 = ['-q3']
```

Right now I'm getting this:

```
new_list1 = ['-x', '-q3']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def toggle(x):
    if x[0] == '-':
        return x[1:]
    else:
        return '-'+x

list1 = ['p', '-x', 'q123', '-q3']
list2 = ['p56', '-p', '-q123', 'x']
new_list1 = list1.copy()
for y in list1:
    for x in list2:
        if x == toggle(y):
            new_list1.remove(y)
```

this will get you `new_list1 == ['-q3']`

A more time efficient way:

```
list1 = ['p', '-x', 'q123', '-q3']
list2 = ['p56', '-p', '-q123', 'x']
toggled_list2 = set(toggle(y) for y in list2)
new_list2 = list(set(list1).difference(toggled_list2))

# new_list2 == ['-q3']
```

Comment: it's beter (as per PEP8 recommendations) to use `str.startswith()` method

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ['p', '-x', 'q123', '-q3']
list2 = ['p56', '-p', '-q123', 'xr']
    new_list1 = list1.copy()
    for y in list1:
        for x in list2:
            if y == '-'+x:
                new_list1.append(x)`
```

Actually you was close.. Try this and use append function. If it work don't forget to upvote